# knockout binding print function text instead of variable value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm writing a small application in JS and I decided to use Knockout.
Everything work well except from a single value that is not printed correctly and I don't understand why.

This is the html view where error appends (viaggio.arrivo is not visualized, and in place of correct value appears a function code like this "`function c(){if(0 <arguments.length){if ...`" and so on)

```
<input data-bind="value: viaggio.arrivo"  />
```

And this is the javascript View Model.
Code is pretty long so I put it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGDwy/).

```
     function ViewModel() {
        function Viaggiatore(nome, cognome, eta, citta) {
            var self = this;
            self.nome = nome; self.cognome = cognome;
            self.eta = ko.observable(eta);
            self.citta = ko.observable(citta);
        }
        function Viaggio(viaggiatore, partenza, arrivo, mete) {
            var self = this;
            self.viaggiatore = ko.computed(viaggiatore);
            self.partenza = ko.computed(partenza);
            self.arrivo = ko.observable(arrivo);
            self.mete = ko.computed(mete);
        }

        self.viaggiatore = new Viaggiatore("Mario", "Rossi", 35, "Como");
        self.viaggio = new Viaggio(
            function(){ return self.viaggiatore.nome+" "+self.viaggiatore.cognome; },
            function(){ return self.viaggiatore.citta; },
            "Roma",
            function(){ return "mete" ;}
        );          
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need brackets on one of your parameters, like so:

```
<p data-bind="text: viaggio.partenza()"></p>
```

Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mGDwy/2/